# How do I prove this determinant reduction?

Tags: determinant

How do I prove the following ?

$$
(\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma)
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ 
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 &  y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha x_1 + \beta y_1 & \gamma x_1+ \delta y_1 & 1 \\ 
\alpha x_2 + \beta y_2 &\gamma x_2+ \delta y_2  & 1 \\
\alpha x_3+ \beta y_3 &  \gamma x_3+ \delta y_3  & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I am getting $(\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma)$ instead of $(\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma)$. Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} x_1&y_1&1\cr
x_2&y_2&1\cr
x_3&y_3&1\cr\end{pmatrix} $$

and 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha& \gamma&0\cr
\beta&\delta&0\cr
0&0&1\cr \end{pmatrix}$$

Compute $AB$.